# cakePHP not able to use a global variable in my views

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp v2.3.4

Have set in the /app/Config/bootstrap.php a global variable as follow;

```
Configure::write('Bike.Frontwheel','Gazette, 16 inch');
```

I am not able to see this value in my any of my views, what am I doing wrong?
I am able to change the value in a controller with:

```
Configure::write('Bike.Frontwheel', $Data['Bike']['description']);
```

Code in the view:

```
<?php echo Configure::read('Bike.Frontwheel'); ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the variable in your controller so that it gets passed to your view:

```
$this->set('front_wheel', Configure::read('Bike.Frontwheel'));
```

Then in your view:

```
<?php echo $front_wheel; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, maybe a silly question [novice] but do I always need to set it in each controller where I want to use this global variable in my view?

Comment: Thanks, I noticed you clarified this below :-)

Answer (score 0):

try in the config folder,

for this you need to create a file in the `config` folder & load that in the `bootstrap` as shown

```
Configure::load('custom');
```

this shows that your file is custom.php
now you can write as

```
$config['Bike.Frontwheel'] = 'Gazette, 16 inch';
```

where ever you need you can call this as

```
$variable = Configure::read('Bike.Frontwheel');
```

Comment: @Scott Harwell, I've said this because he has tried in the bootstrap, instead of this we can have a common file to keep some standard values into a specific variable so that we can use them ANYWHERE.,

Comment: The configs set in the bootstrap are available everywhere in your app, such as controllers.  And, the source of the config is irrelevant for answering this question.  But, you should not call them directly from a view.  Rather, get the data you need for the view in the controller and then pass all data to the view (i.e., what I proposed in my answer).

Comment: @Nagendra, but isn't this something more complicated, I assume I could easily add a few more global variables in the bootstrap file, and still not sure how your solution would solve my problem, could you please explain a bit more in detail why your suggestion should be better? I know many roads lead to Rome, but not all are the shortest and easy to drive ;-)

Comment: Guys, it seems that a Global variable is more behaving like a Constant, I am able to change the value in a controller for it's related view. The new value is lost however in a view from an other controller [set to the default in my bootstrap file]
All I want is to be able to change the value of this global variable throughout my application whenever needed and be able to display this new value in my views.
Any suggestions?

Comment: @Nick you should be able to set your global value from anywhere by calling Configure::write() again.  However, if you need to do it based on something in your view, then I would suggest that you create a ajax call back to a controller method to make the change.  There really shouldn't be any logic that changes this type of value in a view.